# Difference between normal oil and hybrid oil

Tags: toyota, oil, oil-change, camry, hybrid

Trying to buy some oil for my 2020 hybrid toyota camry after finding out its MUCH more expensive in the dealer and they only fill it with semi-synthetic oil. I found the same oil from shell, both are fully synthetic and both are the same viscosity, but one says on the packaging that its designed for hybrid cars. My question is is there any difference between them or is it just marketing because the one with hybrid on it is more expensive.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest checking this page: https://www.startmycar.com/toyota/camry-hybrid/guides/what-engine-oil-does-my-car-need
Also your owners manual probably has an answer to your question. The link above also did mention that switching from mineral oil to synthetic oil can block oil lines and filters.

Comment: Thank you but I know what kind of oil my engine needs, I just need to know if there's a difference between 2 seemingly identical oils. I already looked at the owners manual and it doesn't say anything about hybrid branded oils, and the myth about switching from conventional or semi synthetic oil to fully synthetic oil blocking oil lines was busted long ago.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Your answer as shown is basically a "link only" answer, with very little else to go on. If you find information which is valid to answer the question, then bring the information here and use the link as reference. Also, I'd like to see a valid reference to your assertion about synthetic oil, because if anything, synthetic oil is going to clean out the gunk left behind by dyno oil, not the other way around. The old wives' tales of old about synthetic oils are just that, wives' tales. Just like a lot of things on the internet, should not be believed

Answer (score 0):

The motor oils referenced are for all intents & purposes identical. Same base stock, same additive package, same viscosity, same refining method.